# mongoose aggregate returning empty array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two model and I want to find the last status of each id in customer model from the status model, I'm using aggregate here, but when I console log things it shows,  empty, can anyone help please .............................................

/// customer model

///table name is crmcustomers in database

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var schemaOptions = {
    timestamps: true,
    toJSON: {
        virtuals: true
    }
};

var CrmCustomerSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    shop_name: String,
    address: String,
    phone: { type: String, unique: true},
    comment: String,
    email: String,
    website : String,
    interest: String,
    reference : String,



  }, schemaOptions);


  var CrmCustomer = mongoose.model('CrmCustomer', CrmCustomerSchema);

  module.exports = CrmCustomer;
```

/// status model

///table name is crmcustomerstatuses in database

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

  var schemaOptions = {
      timestamps: true,
      toJSON: {
          virtuals: true
      }
  };

var CrmCustomerStatusSchema = new Schema({
crm_id : String,
name: String,
shop_name : String,
status : String

}, schemaOptions);

var CrmCustomerStatus = mongoose.model('CrmCustomerStatus', CrmCustomerStatusSchema);

module.exports = CrmCustomerStatus;
```

////query

```
 CrmCustomer.aggregate([

        {
            "$lookup": {
                "from": "crmcustomerstatus",
                "localField": "_id",
                "foreignField": "crm_id",
                "as": "result"
            }
        },

     ]).exec(function(err, results){
        console.log(results);
     })
```

///result

```
[ { _id: 5a1cf755b5268904a476c7d2,
    updatedAt: 2017-11-28T05:42:45.239Z,
    createdAt: 2017-11-28T05:42:45.239Z,
    name: 'istiaque ahmad',
    shop_name: 'les mecaron',
    address: 'mirpur',
    phone: '01764199657',
    email: 'nahid@bond.com',
    website: 'xccxxxxx',
    comment: 'dsfsdf',
    interest: 'dsfsdf',
    reference: 'dsfsdfsdf',
    __v: 0,
    result: [] } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Reason for getting empty result is `_id` in `CrmCustomer` schema is of type of ObjectId, whereas `crm_id` in `CrmCustomerStatus` schema is of type String

Modified CrmCustomerStatus Schema

```
var CrmCustomerStatusSchema = new Schema({
crm_id : ObjectId,
name: String,
shop_name : String,
status : String
```